# Adobe Reader doesn't show some texts generated by PDFKit

Tags: pdf, adobe, pdfkit, reader

I have written a pdf generator with PDFKit. If I open the saved PDF-file with Adobe Reader some texts won't be shown. In some other PDF-viewer programs and the viewers of modern browsers all texts will be shown correctly.
Do you know somethng about that? Is it known?

Note: All texts have the standard font 'Helvetica'. So the font formatting isn't the problem (I think). The texts which won't be shown are texts set as footer and header. Maybe the coordinates of the set texts are for Adobe Reader a problem?

My simple code to add these texts:

```
doc.text('My text', posX, posY);
```

[Example PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pfpjjziqz3l7olo/example%20document.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: please include a runnable example of code (function) that reproduces the problem, so someone with PDF expertise might be able to help you identify the issue.

Comment: Similarly, share for analysis an example PDF which displays differently in Adobe Reader.

Comment: Note: I added a link to an example pdf document.

Comment: Any update on this?